# How to add text above the image?

Tags: react-native, react-native-swiper

I use `react-native-swiper` and i want to add a text above my image.

I try to set style `container`  `image` `paragraph`, it is still not working.

What should i do about the style setting ?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Image, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import Swiper from 'react-native-swiper';

const dimensions = Dimensions.get('window').width;

class About extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Swiper
          style={styles.wrapper}
          height={200}
          paginationStyle={{bottom: 10}}
        >
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Image style={styles.image} source={require('../img/home_service_bg1.jpg')} />
            <Text style={styles.paragraph}>How to let me show above the img.</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <Image source={require('../img/home_service_bg2.jpg')} style={styles.img}/>
          </View>
        </Swiper>

        <View style={{ flex: 2 }}>
          <Text>Hi</Text>
        </View>
      </View>   
    );
  }
}

const styles = {
  wrapper: {
  },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'stretch',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  image: {
    flexGrow:1,
    height:null,
    width:null,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent:'center',
  },
  paragraph: {
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
};

export default About;
```

Here is my situation now:
[image]

I hope it becomes like this:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`position="absolute"` will make it work as Android `RelativeLayout`.

If you want set view on top set `marginTop to 0`.

After seeing your requirement. You can simply use `ImageBackground`

```
  <ImageBackground source={...} style={{width: '100%', height: '100%'}}>
    <Text>Inside</Text>
  </ImageBackground>
```

See [facebook docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html#background-image-via-nesting)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but when i add `position="absolute"` in `container` or `image` or `paragraph` style,  my image will be gone on the screen.

Comment: I am not getting you, can you post an final UI image, that you want to achieve.

Comment: Sure, i have uploaded two image in my question, take a look please~

Comment: Thank you very much, its working. I know how to achieve it now.